# 2 alerts from 2 identical scripts not working properly

Tags: alert, pine-script

I have created a strategy for pair 1 which has this syntax to open and close positions:

```
strategy.entry(id='long', direction=strategy.long, when=buy_signals,  alert_message = '{...."pair":"pair1"...}')

strategy.close(id='long', when=sell_signals ,  alert_message = '{..."pair":"pair1"...}')





if buy_signals

    alert('entry_alert', alert.freq_once_per_bar)

else if sell_signals

    alert('close_alert', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

From this I have created an alert which sends signals correctly to the email.

Then I made a copy of the script and just replaced the name, strategy name and  "pair2"  instead of "pair1"  in the alert message.
Similarly I have created an alert which sends signals correctly to email.

What is now happening and I need assistance to understand is that today after I changed pairs on the chart , added and removed several indicators/strategies to the chart to test,  the first alert send alerts with "pair2"  in the alert message instead of "pair1".  I have removed everything from the chart and added it again, but it still sends messages with "pair2" My feeling is that TV is very sensitive to what once was on the chart and/or previous scripts and something seems to be somehow cached between these two scripts or between the 2 alerts while switching between them on the chart.

Is there a way to have the two alerts working fine , each one with its own alert message?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have the two alerts working fine , each one with its
> own alert message?

Yes of course. When the alert has been created no any changes on the chart affect on it. If you have problem with particular alert you can send the bug report to TV Help Ceneter specifying the problem alert id.

Comment: Hi Andrey, thank you for the answer. I could solve the pairs and alert 1 with pair one is working fine.  I will search how to send to TV Help Center, it would be new for me.

Comment: Right bottom corner, question sign in the circle, "Alerts"->"Still need help? Open a support ticket and we'll get back to you shortly"